# How can I root my LG Optimus M?

Tags: rooting, lg-optimus-one

How can I root my LG Optimus M MS690 on Metro PCS? I've tried Gingerbreak, Superoneclick, and z4root without luck.

Comment: Your question is kind of confusing, to be honest. Are you saying your device is an "LG Optimus SH"? I've never seen that device, and Google doesn't turn up any results. Do you have a link to any information about it (the typical one for MetroPCS is the [Optimus M](http://www.bestbuy.com/site/MetroPCS+-+LG+Optimus+M+No-Contract+Mobile+Phone+-+Silver/1792294.p?id=1218291942669&skuId=1792294), I thought)? Also, Gingerbread is 2.3 or higher, 2.2.2 would be Froyo. Is 2.2.2 what you have running on the device?

Comment: Ok I wanna thank you for helping me OK here it is. It is a optimus LG-MS690 Android version is 2.2.2 which is froyo the base band version is MS690ZV6_00.6050 THE Kernel version is 2.6.32.9 build#2 Jun 17 2011 build number frg83g and the S.W.version MS690zv6 and metro pcs is the carrier

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% that this is for your device, I can't find anything on the LG Optimus SH, [these instructions](http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-root-and-unroot-lg-optimus-s-ls670-44246/) are for the LG Optimus S (LS670)

**Requirements**

1. Download and install the .net Framework. Part of this utility software is needed by the rooting application. Get the .net Framework [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=9cfb2d51-5ff4-4491-b0e5-b386f32c0992&displaylang=en).
2. The rooting application will also need the Visual C++ 2008 Redistribute Package. You can get this here.
3. This process will need a Windows PC which runs either Windows Vista or Windows 7.
   It is also best to have a fully charged battery before you perform this process.

**Instructions**

1. Download the rooting application from [here](http://www.androphiles.com/files/android/dwalton/GingersnapRootUtilityForWindows.zip).
2. Unzip the downloaded file to have access to the main rooting application.
3. Download and install the USB driver for the device from [here](http://s3.amazonaws.com/lgforum.com/resources/assets/534/original/LGLS670.zip?1292363411). If you have successfully connected the device to your PC before, you don’t need to do this.
4. Enable USB debugging in the Optimus S. To do this, just follow this path Settings > Applications > Development and check the box for USB Debugging.
5. Connect the device to your PC via USB cable.
6. Open the notifications window on the device and make sure “USB debugging connected” is listed under “Ongoing”.
7. Go to the folder where you unzipped the rooting files. Right click on “Gingersnap.exe” and then choose “Run as administrator”.
8. Click on the Root button to complete the rooting process. And, if you just came back here to Unroot the Optimus S, then feel free to click the Unroot button.