# Root android lg ms690 version 2.2.1

Tags: rooting

Does anyone know how I can root my lg ms690. It is android version 2.2.1. Build # FRG83. Kernel version 2.6.32.9. SW version MS690ZV4. HW version 1.1. PRL verdion 3042. ERI version 1003. I have tried both zroot and gingerbreak, both with no success.

Comment: @bmdixon Please see the [rooting tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/rooting/info), we do not close rooting questions towards that one since 1/2012 (oops!) – but instead permitting exactly one "how-do-I-root-my-X" question per device. The LG MS690 is not yet [listed in our index](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1184/16575), so I will add it now (you might wish to retract your close-vote ;)

Comment: Isn't the MS690 the same as the "LG Optimus M MS690" http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19036/how-can-i-root-my-lg-optimus-m? From a quick search they appeared to be the same to me... Appologies if they're not the same.

Comment: **[towelroot by geohot](https://towelroot.com/)** claims to root pretty any version of Android. I didn't try it myself, but it's worth a try. Please report back when tried whether it was successful, so I make it an answer ;)

Comment: @bmdixon Ooops? In that case you're correct, but rather should link to *that* question with your VTC :) Found no "real proof", but GSMArena lists the M+ as "MS-695", which is a good indicator. // **EVA:** Can you confirm your device being the "Optimus M"?

Comment: I did wonder which one I should link to... Guess I picked the wrong one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using POOT? Download from Playstore and confirm if it supports your device. It works for most Android 2.x devices.